# looping over a command in a task in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, parallel-processing

I have the following playbook,

```
---
  - name: ReadJsonfile
    hosts: localhost
    vars:
      input: "{{ lookup('file','hostinfo.json_pb') | from_json }}"
    tasks:
    - name: Image Server(s)
      command: python3 image.pyc {{item.key}} {{item.value.version}}
      with_dict: "{{input}}"`
    - name: configure-firstnet on a server
      command: python3 configure_firstnet.pyc {{item.key}} {{item.value.version}} {{item.value.netconf}}
      with_dict: "{{input}}"
```

The hostinfo.json looks like this,

```
{
 "hosts":
  {
    "abc":
    {
      "username": "root",
      "password": "welcome1",
      "password2": "WElcome1",
      "version": "19.17",
      "toversion" : "19.18.0.0.0",
      "netconf": "bonding",
      "baseversion": "18.8.0.0"
    },
    "xyz":
    {
      "username": "root",
      "password": "welcome1",
      "password2": "WElcome1",
      "version": "19.18",
      "toversion" : "19.18.0.0.0",
      "netconf": "bonding",
      "baseversion": "18.8.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to run the above command on both the machines concurrently.

```
python3 image.pyc abc 19.17
python3 image.pyc xyz 19.18
```

Note that this is a single command and part of the same task. How can we achieve this so that command runs for both abc and xyz and then moves on to the next task after completion.

I tried this,

```
---
  - name: ReadJsonfile
    hosts: localhost
    vars:
      input: "{{ lookup('file','hostinfo.json_pb') | from_json }}"
    tasks:
    - name: Updating the captured data in the default payload file
      command: python3 updatejson.py
    - name: Image Server(s)
      command: python3 image.pyc {{item.key}} {{item.value.version}}
      register: async_out
      async: 7200
      poll: 10
      with_dict: "{{input}}"
```

but the playbook waits for the image.pyc run on abc to comlplete first before moving on to xyz.

If I do the following,

```
    - name: Image Server(s)
      command: python3 image.pyc {{item.key}} {{item.value.version}}
      register: async_out
      async: 7200
      poll: 0
      with_dict: "{{input}}"`
```

The task immediately runs the command on both the servers and goes to the next task i.e. "configure-firstnet on a server" , which I don't want as second task is dependent on completeness of previous task.

What I want :

```
python3 image.pyc abc 19.17
python3 image.pyc xyz 19.18
```

to run in parallel and finish before moving on to next task

Can someone please help/advice how to achieve parallel execution of commands in the same task before moving into the next task ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ansible runs each task on all hosts affected by a play before starting the next task on any host, using 5 forks. If you want to change this default behavior, you can use a different strategy plugin, change the number of forks, or apply one of several keywords like serial.

The default behavior described above is the `linear` strategy. Ansible offers other strategies, including the `free` strategy, which allows each host to run until the end of the play as fast as it can.

Add this to the header of your play:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  strategy: free
  tasks:
```

Comment: Can you share the working playbook for the solution above ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that the syntax might not be right but the way you could do is to run the task as a Linux command using the multiline string

```
- name: name of it
  command: |
    python3 image.pyc abc 19.17
    python3 image.pyc xyz 19.18
```

All the command does, is run the bash command. I do things like this regularly with powershell, where I will run an entire powershell script from a win_shell command.

The advantage of this solution is that all machines will be at the same stage before continuing.

If you must take the variables from an external file, then you could loop over your json file. Each loop would add to a list of strings, which you could then join with the new line character. You could then run the joined listed as the command.

Comment: Didn't get it. Can you share the snippet ?